# Find the last day of the semestre of a given date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to implement a plsql function that takes a date as parameter and return the last day of the semestre of the parameter date.

```
function find_lastday_of_semetre(p_datdeb IN date := current_date)
      return date IS
  begin
      declare
          semestreLastDay date;
      begin

            -- semestreLastDay = the last day of the semestre of the p_datdeb
          return semestreLastDay ;
      end;
  end find_lastday_of_semetre;
```

For example :

- if p_date is 12/02/2021 then semestreLastDay = 30/06/2021
- if p_date is 01/06/2022 than semestreLastDay = 30/06/2022
- if p_date is 20/08/2023 than semestreLastDay = 31/12/2023

I figure out how to get the last day of the month, the quarter and the year based in a date param but I couldn't figure out how to get the last day of the semestre.

Get the last day of the quarter

```
semestreLastDay := TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(p_datdeb, 3), 'Q') - 1
```

Get the last day of the month

```
semestreLastDay := LAST_DAY(p_datdeb)
```

Get the last day of the year

```
semestreLastDay := ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(p_datdeb, 'YEAR'), 12) - 1
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the last day of the semester supposed to be determined in plain English?

Comment: Is it always either June 30 or December 31, or are other semester last days possible?

Comment: @EJEGYED The last day of the semestre is either June 30 or Decembre 31 at the date param year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you put the code for the function inside a nested block. I assume it was for no reason (just lack of knowledge).

You don't need a local variable, either - you can put the computation directly in the `return` statement, as I show below.

I use `TRUNC(date_variable, 'YEAR')` to truncate to the beginning of the year, then I subtract one day, and I use `ADD_MONTHS` to add either six or 12 months to the result, depending on whether the month component of the input date is `<= 6` or `> 6`.

I also correct the spelling - you have "semetre" (with a missing "s") in your code. Especially bad since "seme***s***tre" is the main concept in your task.

So - here is a minimalist way to write your function:

```
create or replace function 
    find_lastday_of_semestre(p_datdeb IN date := current_date)
    return date
as
begin
    return add_months(trunc(p_datdeb, 'year') - 1, 
               case when extract(month from p_datdeb) <= 6 then 6 else 12 end);
end find_lastday_of_semestre;
/
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Yes it is not a lack of knowledge, the function that I asked is just a part of the solution that I am trying to implement . and yes, we can delete the nested block.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the month and check whether it's greater than 6 or not and return date from parts : year from the input date and 06-30 or 12-31 :

```
return to_date(CASE
                 WHEN extract(month from p_datdeb) <= 6 THEN to_char(p_datdeb, 'yyyy') || '-' || '06-30'
                 ELSE to_char(p_datdeb, 'yyyy') || '-' || '12-31'
               END, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```